# error in exporting pdf with large data using datatable and pdfmake

Tags: laravel

I'm having trouble exporting large data in pdf using datatable, pdfmake. Does anyone has solution for that? thanks in advance. Im using laravel framework

Comment: Can we see some code? how you try to implement it.

Comment: I am using this solution, DOMPDF wrapper for Laravel, which works very well: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: @EddyTheDove - i'm just declaring the button in datatable then it will show a button. here is the sample code - buttons:[ extend: pdfFlash]

Comment: @John Doe - the problem is i need to export the data that was filtered according to user action.

Comment: @user6036956 it would be nice if you share the relevant code ..